# Capturing Bluetooth / WiFi on an SDR

Tags: software-defined-radio, rtl-sdr, usrp

I have a question, right before purchasing SDR for some tests:

Commercial hardware for bluetooth (even Ubertooth) allows you to receive packets on a 1MHz channel. Which practicaly means that if you, and the transmitter, are not listening to the same channel, you will not see the transmittion. pretty clear.

My questions is this. if by the spec, for example USRP - can listen to 160MHz channel, does it mean it can listen in parellel and collect packets for more than one bluetooth channel?

If not, why?

Thanks Jen

Comment: https://rtl-sdr.com/tag/bluetooth has some information about sniffing and decoding nrf24l01 and ble with rtl-sdr dongles.